# pry session during rspec test ends on any input

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to pause an rspec test using `binding.pry` to understand why it fails. Here is a simplified version:

```
def copy_db
  binding.pry
  puts 'hello world'
end
```

The `binding.pry` pauses execution but any input in the session causes it to end. Any ideas why this would be? This is not a rails project.

Comment: Do you have `require pry` in the file ?

Comment: Sometimes, `pry` corrupts my terminal, and it behaves the way you're experiencing, and when I reload the terminal, it works. I face this quite often on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the previous answer was sufficient, but another thing you could try besides binding.pry is using the byebug gem.

In your Gemfile add:

```
gem "byebug"
```

In the terminal (at the root of the project directory) run:

```
$ bundle install
```

Require 'byebug' at the top of your code and insert a 'debugger' wherever you want to set a breakpoint:

```
require 'byebug'
def copy_db
    debugger
    puts 'hello world'
end
```

And it will pause rspec and enter the byebug debugger, which lets you display the values of various variables as you step through each line.

```
[1, 4] in path/to/your/file.rb
     1:  def copy_db
     2:      debugger
=>   3:      puts 'hello world'
     4:  end
(byebug)_
```